# Woocommerce How to hide product tab

Tags: wordpress, tabs, woocommerce, product

I'm trying to hide or remove the tab itself but want to keep the product description. Is there a way to do this?

https://www.absolutept.com/product/electric-stimulation-machine-ev906/

See how the word "description" appears - I want to remove that and the dot in front of it but keep everything else.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to remove this code snippet:

```
<ul class="tabs wc-tabs">
  <li class="description_tab active">
    <a href="#tab-description">Description</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

That should solve your problem.

Comment: If you're removing any of the html.  Make sure you don't remove it from the regular woocommerce files because if you update the plugin your changes will be overwritten.  I would overwrite the file by creating a new woocommerce folder inside your theme folder and replacing the woocommerce file.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add this to your functions.php file or custom plugin that you use as an alternate to your functions.php file

```
add_filter('woocommerce_product_description_heading', false);
```

I haven't double checked it.  But it should remove the title